# Difference between a Embedded controller and a northbridge

Tags: computer-architecture

I found the terms 'Embedded Controller' 'Northbridge' 'southbridge' 'Platform Controller Hub' 'super I-O' and I am not sure to understand the difference.

Northbridge and southbride difference is clear as it's explained [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing))

EC is also explained [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller).

However no mention of each other is on neither page. And I have a feeling that they might be the same?

I am trying to write on an EC register and got confused by the North/southbridge notions. (note this EC is [IT8570](http://dl.iranfso.com/DataSheet/IC/ITE/IT8570_IT8571_A_V0.3.4_092909.pdf) for reference).

Comment: An embedded controller is a  microcontroller with a self-contained system; processor, memory, peripherals, clock, timer Starting from <$1.  A northbridge is not.

Comment: In the Intel x86 world, the southbridge was the chip that, in part, bridged the ISA bus to the PCI bus. (In some incarnations, it performed "super I/O" functions.) It represented more than half of the silicon bugs regularly found due to the complexity. (For example, the ISA bus supports DMA. The PCI supports "bursts" but not prolonged DMA transfers.) Given the description on wiki, the idea could apply differently in various designs. So you'll have to reference each to work out the details. There's no "bright line" definition, it seems.

Comment: You should maybe ask what they have in common. I think the differences are quite obvious if you read the articles you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Northbridge and "Embedded Controller" have absolutely nothing in common, but they have a distant relationship. The situation is fully explained on the referenced Wikipedia page, on  the second [block diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Motherboard_diagram.svg).

In short, Northbridge provides a very high-speed level of connectivity to high-speed components of PC like memory and graphics, plus to a somewhat narrower path to Southbridge.

The Southbridge provides connectivity and interfaces to less-high-speed peripherals like USB, SATA, PATA, Networking, PCI bus etc, and includes so-called LPC - Low Pin Count bus, which is 4-bit wide.

The LPC bus connects to "Super-I/O" controller, which provides connectivity to low-speed peripherals as UART, PS/2 keyboard/mouse, parallel port, floppy, BIOS flash, power management functions, fan control, clock control, etc etc.

The confusion arises because the Wikipedia forgot to mention that the "SuperIO" is also called "Embedded Controller". Notable manufacturers are SMSC/MCHP, ITE, Winbond, etc. Usually the chip has a rectangular shape with 128 pins, easy recognizable on PC mainboards.

ADDITION: There are also some beefier versions of "embedded controllers", mostly for small server platforms, like [Winbond WPCM450](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/Embedded_BMC_IPMI.pdf), dubbed as "Baseboard Management controller", which also includes a simple VGA graphics core, so a user can see full-scale boot and system messages without hassles to add a video card. The chip has a lot of other useful features.

Comment: Thanks! It's more clear now!
By chance do you know how to write on a SuperIO/EC flash memory? I am trying to drive a IT8570 PWM from windows user space.

Comment: @PaddleStroke, sorry, I have no idea. But I am sure that writes to flash memory are seriously protected, so you will need some secure access key or something to disable hardware protection and unlock the memory. Section 6.3 from ITE datasheet provides a lot of words regarding Flash Interface Bridge.

Comment: There are some old motherboards that have both an EC / KBC and a SuperIO